# Why does Celery periodic tasks fire a function only once

Tags: python, django, celery

I've built a small web scraper function to get some data from the web and populate it to my db which works just well.
Now I would like to fire this function periodically every 20 seconds using Celery periodic tasks.
I walked through the docu and everything seems to be set up for development (using redis as broker).

This is my `tasks.py` file in project/stocksapp where my periodically fired functions are:

```
# Celery imports

from celery.task.schedules import crontab
from celery.decorators import periodic_task
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from datetime import timedelta

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

# periodic functions

@periodic_task(
    run_every=(timedelta(seconds=20)),
    name="getStocksDataDax",
    ignore_result=True
)
def getStocksDataDax():
    print("fired")
```

Now when I start the worker, the function seems to be fired once and only once (the database gets populated). But after that, the function doesn't get fired anymore, although the console suggests it:

```
C:\Users\Jonas\Desktop\CFD\CFD>celery -A CFD beat -l info
celery beat v4.4.2 (cliffs) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
LocalTime -> 2020-05-15 23:06:29
Configuration ->
    . broker -> redis://localhost:6379/0
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
[2020-05-15 23:06:29,990: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...

[2020-05-15 23:06:30,024: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task getStocksDataDax (getStocksDataDax)
[2020-05-15 23:06:50,015: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task getStocksDataDax (getStocksDataDax)
[2020-05-15 23:07:10,015: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task getStocksDataDax (getStocksDataDax)
[2020-05-15 23:07:30,015: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task getStocksDataDax (getStocksDataDax)
[2020-05-15 23:07:50,015: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task getStocksDataDax (getStocksDataDax)
[2020-05-15 23:08:10,016: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task getStocksDataDax (getStocksDataDax)
[2020-05-15 23:08:30,016: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task getStocksDataDax (getStocksDataDax)
[2020-05-15 23:08:50,016: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task getStocksDataDax (getStocksDataDax)
```

project/project/celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os

from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'CFD.settings')

app = Celery('CFD',
             broker='redis://localhost:6379/0',
             backend='amqp://',
             include=['CFD.tasks'])

app.conf.broker_transport_options = {'visibility_timeout': 3600}
# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

The function itself runs about 1 second totally.

Where could basically be an issue in this setup to make the worker/celery fire the function every 20 seconds as supposed to?

Comment: From what is seen here beat is properly creating tasks, did you run a worker process also with beat? also task in your question does not have any code in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`celery -A CFD beat -l info` only starts the Celery beat process. You should have a separate Celery worker process - in a different terminal run something like `celery -A CFD worker -c 8 -O fair -l info`.